# Using Sharepoint Online, multiple issues with Custom Calendar

Tags: list, css, calendar, events, embedded

I have multiple problems with a custom calendar I've made for a shared team calendar. I am using Sharepoint Online, I read online that these use the version 2016.

Just to clarify, I am by no means good at code.

Problems:

1. Adding month list and key to main widget
2. Font colour on time
3. Get rid of scroll bars around Calendar widget
4. Events on widget right side, extend calendar width
5. Make hyperlink "Master Calendar," inactive
6. Add button not function for non-admins

So, people understand the situation I will share the structure that lead to the widget being displayed on the front page.

The problems are explained more in depth further down.

Please find supporting code in the comments!

**Master Calendar Page**
[image: Master Calendar Page]

**Master Calendar Web Part**
[image: Master Calendar Web Part]

I created a web part page with the Calendar being pulled in as a Calendar web part and a script editor to cut down space around the calendar so it fits better on the Main Page.
The script editor I changed to have the width and height at 0 plus hidden so it doesn’t take up space in the widget boundaries.

**Main page - Calendar embed widget 
[image: Main Page - Calendar embed widget]

**Problems Explained**

**Font colour on time** 
[image: Event time font colour]

The time on the event is white and hard to see with a backdrop of yellow. Is it possible to change the font colour to black while keeping it white on the rest of events that aren’t yellow?

**Adding month list and key to main widget**
[image: Month list and key]

How do I add these two sections to the web part so it will show up on the main page?

**“Get rid of scroll bars around Calendar widget,” & “Events on widget right side, extend calendar width.”**
[image: Scrolled right Calendar widget]

I originally got rid of the scroll bars. However, adding code to extend the titles so the events with a long title will show up in the overview, this made it so some overextended the width of the calendar. How do I fix this?

**Make hyperlink "Master Calendar," inactive**
How do I make the title hyperlink “Master Calendar,” inactive?

**Add button not function for non-admins**
Only a certain number of people should be able to edit the calendar, how do I make it so nobody can do that but a select few?

[image]

Comment: Please find code attached
Custom Colours: https://shrib.com/#46E.wrVaB0ftmFSfu7_j
Script Editor:https://shrib.com/#z2PUzYj1gY7hEAQcnF46
Web Part https://shrib.com/#EGiXsCbJc1S0JezDQDcJ